# SQL - Incorrect syntax near keyword

Tags: sql, syntax

Small problem with my query here:

```
CREATE VIEW rental_view
AS 
   SELECT 
       m.movie_id, movie_name, co.copy_id, 
       f.format_id, format_name, cu.customer_id, 
       (first_name + ' ' + surname) AS customer_name, 
       rental_id, rental_date, return_date, 
       ISNULL(return_date, CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, rental_date, GETDATE() ) AS rental_duration 
   FROM 
         movie AS m 
   INNER JOIN copy AS co ON m.movie_id = co.movie_id
   INNER JOIN format AS f ON co.format_id = f.format_id
   INNER JOIN rental ON co.copy_id = rental.copy_id
   INNER JOIN customer AS cu ON rental.customer_id = cu.customer_id
```

Results in error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1,
>   Procedure rental_view, Line 3   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

I had a long attempt at this one and can't solve it.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing two parenthesis on this line:

```
AS SELECT 
    m.movie_id, movie_name, co.copy_id, f.format_id, format_name, 
    cu.customer_id, (first_name + ' ' + surname) AS customer_name, 
    rental_id, rental_date, return_date, 
    ISNULL(
        return_date, 
        CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, rental_date, GETDATE()))) AS rental_duration
```

Anyway your syntax is wrong in other parts:

- `CAST` wants the field to be converted, keyword AS and new type (see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast))
- `DATEDIFF` wants two params (see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)) <-- this if you're using MySql; with MS-SQL is correct

Comment: Where should the parenthesis be?

Comment: @Owen two more after the last **)**

Comment: @Owen: after `GETDATE())` you need two more parenthesis as I wrote ;)

Comment: Dude I think parenthesis should be at the end after rental_duration because the cast will expect an AS after it

Comment: @AllanChua: no, parenthesis should be where I put them because the final AS is given to provide an alias to the computed field. Anyway, as you noticed, query is wrong in other parts as I wrote in my answer :)

Comment: If you're answer is executed in SQL server it will throw you this error Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Procedure rental_view, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.

Comment: But you're right anyway :) the query he posted is wrong at the first point because the alias is for the column and the cast expects a type inside it lol :)

Comment: @Owen: did you solve your problem? Did you examine your mistakes and solved them?

Comment: @Marco Yes I did, thanks, most of that one line was dodgy but I've sorted it out thanks to the help on here.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  CREATE VIEW rental_view
  AS SELECT m.movie_id, 
movie_name, 
co.copy_id, 
f.format_id, 
format_name, 
cu.customer_id, 
(first_name + ' ' + surname) AS customer_name, 
rental_id, 
rental_date, 
return_date,
ISNULL(return_date,
CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, rental_date, GETDATE()) AS *type desired here*)) AS name of column
  FROM movie as m 
  INNER JOIN copy AS co
  ON m.movie_id = co.movie_id
  INNER JOIN format AS f
  ON co.format_id = f.format_id
  INNER JOIN rental 
  ON co.copy_id = rental.copy_id
  INNER JOIN customer AS cu
  ON rental.customer_id = cu.customer_id
```

Comment: I think you're putting parenthesis in the wrong place. Anyway I've already given the answer _"you're missing parenthesis"_ ;)

Comment: Your edited post is still wrong: `DATEDIFF` wants just two params ;)

Comment: DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate ) see (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Maybe buddy, the problem is with the kid he did not state what kind of server he uses but with the parameters he has in the DATEDIFF Function its more of a MS SQL SERVER

Comment: It is MS SQL SERVER sorry, really should have mentioned.